# I need to create Devices in to Traccar by directly inserting values into the database

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, gps

I am trying to link Traccar and another system, for that I need to create Devices in to Traccar by directly inserting values into the database (or calling a API if their is any ), I tried this by inserting values in the table 'devices' and then linking that device with a user by inserting a row in 'users_devices'. Other than these two entries I didn’t do anything else. While I use the Traccar Web Service I still don’t see any device that I created. I think I am missing some entries. can anyone Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Traccar caches some data in memory, so inserting directly into the database might not work for some things. I would recommend to use [Traccar web API](https://www.traccar.org/traccar-api/).

Comment: What i change to show my device from db.i really tired

Comment: You need to use API for adding and linking devices.

Comment: Where i impliment this api logic after refreshing the url device should seen from database dynamically.

Comment: Yes, if you use API, you will see the device after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use API here is the php code

```
$url = "http://".urlencode($userEmail).":".urlencode($userPassword)."@localhost:8082/api/devices";
$data='{"name":"'.$name.'","uniqueId":"'.$uniqueId.'", "phone":"'.$phone.'", "status":"","lastUpdate":null,"groupId":0, "attributes":'.$attributes.'}';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Connection: Keep-Alive')); 
$data1=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```